# IOS target device screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm new in IOS and face a problem, in my storyboard button and label are in center of screen, but in emulator they are out of screen.

[image: storyboard]

[image: emulator]

Comment: You need to implement either `AutoLayout` or `AutoResizing`.  You may want to try going through a [tutorial like this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **autolayout**:

1. Select your `button`. At the bottom you can see:

[image]

- Select both **Horizontally** and **Vertically** in container. Press Add Consriants
- Now select your `label`. Control and drag from label to `button`. Select **Vertical Spacing**
- Control and Drag again from `label` to `button`. Select **Center horizontally**

This is how you can perform Control and Drag :

http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/auto-layout-control-drag.gif

Also see this link from appcoda

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Follow this stepwise. And let me know if there is an issue.

Look at the below animation:

[image]

Comment: Try using multiplier. Shown in the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Align them to centre by setting Horizontal Centre.Right click on Button and drag to container view and select centre Horizontally. Repeat it for Label as well. It will set them to centre on all screen sizes.